# Development and deployment a Restlet service

Tags: java, restlet

I want to develop REST services with Restlet. I have one class that extends the org.restlet.Application class, and other that extends the org.restlet.resource.ServerResource class.

The first class has one method:

```
public class ServicesApplication extends Application {      
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {

        // Create a router Restlet that routes each call to a

        // new instance of HelloWorldResource.

        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        // Defines only one route

        router.attach("/myServices", Services.class);

        return router;

    }
}
```

And the second class has the different methods of the services, for example a HelloWorld:

```
public class Services extends ServerResource{
    @Get ("hello")
    public void Hello(String name){
        System.out.println("Hello "+name);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how can I deploy my services in Tomcat, do I need to generate a .war and store in the webapps folder of Tomcat??. And I don't know if in the class that implement the ServerResource I need to call to the class that implement to the Application class. Finally I don't know what is exactly the URL to call to "Hello": `http://myDomain:myPort/myServices/hello?name=MyName` ????

Thank in advance

**UPDATE**

I update my app: I change ServicesApplication and now it is an abstract class. Also I add other class that extends to the ServicesApplication class:

```
    public class HelloWorldService extends Services {

    public String Hello(String name){
        System.out.println("Hello "+name);
        return("Hello"+name);
    }
}
```

Of course, `Hello` is an abstract method of `Services` class.

Also I add in `ServicesApplication` this line:

```
router.attach("/helloWorld/{name}", HelloWorldService.class);
```

I'm calling to this method from my navigator:

```
http://localhost:8080/myServices/service/helloWorld/Jesus
```

and this is the response:

```
Hello null
```

How do I have to call to the method???

I only want to do a `Hello +name`. When I have this, I want to develop some GET and POST methods, with JSON String as parameters. But if it's very difficult to develop a simple HelloWorld with **Reslet**, maybe I'll try with RestEasy.

:__(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export your project as a **.war file** and deploy it on your server. Then your path will be `http://localhost:port/Project_Name/myServices`. If you want to pass a parameter you have to add `router.attach("/myServices/{name}", Services.class);`. And you can write `http://localhost:port/Project_Name/myServices/myName`.

Take a look at [this example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/restlet-framework-hello-world-example.html).

Comment: I want to have a lot of methods into Services class. So, where do I need to add `router.attach("/myServices/otherMethod1")`? In the ServicesApplication class, is it true? Can you explain to me if with the line `router.attach("/myServices", Services.class);` I only call to `hello` method?

Comment: Thank for your response and for the example. I think that Restlet is more complicated to use that Jersey or RestEasy :(

Comment: I worked with Restlet last summer and the only thing I remember is that I HATE IT!!! :p And yes Jersey is easier. And for your last question maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608694/multiple-get-methods-in-single-resource-class-with-restlet) can help you.

Comment: Hahahahhahahah, thank you very much @Sergi. Maybe it's possible that I change my app to use Resteasy or Jersey. I only choose Restet because I read that it allows to implement security in a very easy way... (I need to suppport and to develop services with a authentication token)

Answer (score 1):

This page [here](http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/2.1/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/servlet/ServerServlet.html) should get you started and give you some ideas.